# Get the next higher integer value in java

Tags: java, math, numbers

I know I can use Math.java functions to get the floor, ceil or round value for a double or float, but my question is -- Is it possible to always get the higher integer value if a decimal point comes in my value

For example

```
int chunkSize  = 91 / 8 ;
```

which will be equal to 11.375

If I apply floor, ceil or round to this number it will return 11 I want 12.

Simply If I have 11.xxx I need to get 12 , if I have 50.xxx I want 51

Sorry The chunkSize should be int

How can I achieve this?

Comment: "which will be equal to 11.375" - Not correct. You should cast one side.

Comment: *If I apply floor, **ceil** or round to this number it will return 11...* [What makes you think that](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#ceil%28double%29)?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`Math.ceil()` will do the work.

But, your assumption that `91 / 8`  is `11.375` is wrong.
In java, integer division returns the **integer** value of the division (11 in your case).

In order to get the float value, you need to cast (or add .0) to one of the arguments:

```
float chunkSize  = 91 / 8.0 ;
Math.ceil(chunkSize); // will return 12!
```

Answer (score 9):

[ceil](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#ceil%28double%29) is supposed to do just that. I quote:

> Returns the smallest (closest to negative infinity) double value that
>   is greater than or equal to the argument and is equal to a
>   mathematical integer.

EDIT: (thanks to Peter Lawrey): taking another look at your code you have another problem. You store the result of integer division in a float variable: `float chunkSize  = 91 / 8 ;` java looks at the arguments of the division and as they are both integers it performs integer division thus the result is again an **integer** (the result of the division rounded down). Now even if you assign this to the float `chunkSize` it will still be an integer(missing the double part) and ceil, round and floor will all return the same value. To avoid that add a `.0` to `91`: `float chunkSize  = 91.0 / 8;`. This makes one of the arguments double precision and thus double division will be performed, returning a double result.

Comment: It won't help if you have already performed integer division.  `91 / 8 == 11` and `ceil(91 / 8) == 11.0`

Comment: @PeterLawrey good point. I will add this as apparently this is the issue OP's having.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to do integer division rounding up you can do

`x / y` rounded up, assuming x and y are positive

```
long div = (x + y - 1) / y;
```

In your case

```
(91 + 8 - 1) / 8 = 98 / 8 = 12
```

This works because you want to round up (add one) for every value except an exact multiple (which is why you add `y - 1`)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, when you write `float chunkSize  = 91 / 8 ;` it will print 11.0 instead of 11.375

because both 91 and 8 are int type values. For the result to be decimal value, either dividend or divisor

or both have to be decimal value type. So, `float chunkSize = 91.0 / 8;` will result 11.375 and

now you can apply Math.ceil() to get the upper value. `Math.ceil(chunkSize);` will result in 12.0