# Partition a Java 8 Stream

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-8, java-stream

How to implement "partition" operation on Java 8 Stream? By partition I mean, divide a stream into sub-streams of a given size. Somehow it will be identical to Guava [`Iterators.partition()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/20.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterators.html#partition-java.util.Iterator-int-) method, just it's desirable that the partitions are lazily-evaluated Streams rather than List's.

> ### partition
>
> ```
> public static <T> UnmodifiableIterator<List<T>> partition(Iterator<T> iterator,
>                                                           int size)
> ```
>
> Divides an iterator into unmodifiable sublists of the given size (the final list may be smaller). For example, partitioning an iterator containing `[a, b, c, d, e]` with a partition size of 3 yields `[[a, b, c], [d, e]]` -- an outer iterator containing two inner lists of three and two elements, all in the original order.

Comment: Making partitions lazily evaluated is generally infeasible in my experience - what would you expect to happen if you maintained references to several partitions, and then accessed them out of order?

Comment: @JonSkeet - Especially if they are parallel.

Comment: Thanks for your point, Jon, I suspected that. Do you think non-lazy implementation in my own answer below is optimal?

Comment: I think that if I'm more concerned about memory than parallelism, I'd want to work with a stream of "lazy evaluated streams".

Comment: See answer on related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27583623/is-there-an-elegant-way-to-process-a-stream-in-chunks/68913656#68913656

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there an elegant way to process a stream in chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27583623/is-there-an-elegant-way-to-process-a-stream-in-chunks)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

It's impossible to partition the arbitrary source stream to the fixed size batches, because this will screw up the parallel processing. When processing in parallel you may not know how many elements in the first sub-task after the split, so you cannot create the partitions for the next sub-task until the first is fully processed.

However it is possible to create the stream of partitions from the random access `List`. Such feature is available, for example, in my [`StreamEx`](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) library:

```
List<Type> input = Arrays.asList(...);

Stream<List<Type>> stream = StreamEx.ofSubLists(input, partitionSize);
```

Or if you really want the stream of streams:

```
Stream<Stream<Type>> stream = StreamEx.ofSubLists(input, partitionSize).map(List::stream);
```

If you don't want to depend on third-party libraries, you can implement such `ofSubLists` method manually:

```
public static <T> Stream<List<T>> ofSubLists(List<T> source, int length) {
    if (length <= 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("length = " + length);
    int size = source.size();
    if (size <= 0)
        return Stream.empty();
    int fullChunks = (size - 1) / length;
    return IntStream.range(0, fullChunks + 1).mapToObj(
        n -> source.subList(n * length, n == fullChunks ? size : (n + 1) * length));
}
```

This implementation looks a little bit long, but it takes into account some corner cases like close-to-MAX_VALUE list size.

---

If you want parallel-friendly solution for unordered stream (so you don't care which stream elements will be combined in single batch), you may use the collector like this (thanks to @sibnick for inspiration):

```
public static <T, A, R> Collector<T, ?, R> unorderedBatches(int batchSize, 
                   Collector<List<T>, A, R> downstream) {
    class Acc {
        List<T> cur = new ArrayList<>();
        A acc = downstream.supplier().get();
    }
    BiConsumer<Acc, T> accumulator = (acc, t) -> {
        acc.cur.add(t);
        if(acc.cur.size() == batchSize) {
            downstream.accumulator().accept(acc.acc, acc.cur);
            acc.cur = new ArrayList<>();
        }
    };
    return Collector.of(Acc::new, accumulator,
            (acc1, acc2) -> {
                acc1.acc = downstream.combiner().apply(acc1.acc, acc2.acc);
                for(T t : acc2.cur) accumulator.accept(acc1, t);
                return acc1;
            }, acc -> {
                if(!acc.cur.isEmpty())
                    downstream.accumulator().accept(acc.acc, acc.cur);
                return downstream.finisher().apply(acc.acc);
            }, Collector.Characteristics.UNORDERED);
}
```

Usage example:

```
List<List<Integer>> list = IntStream.range(0,20)
                                    .boxed().parallel()
                                    .collect(unorderedBatches(3, Collectors.toList()));
```

Result:

```
[[2, 3, 4], [7, 8, 9], [0, 1, 5], [12, 13, 14], [17, 18, 19], [10, 11, 15], [6, 16]]
```

Such collector is perfectly thread-safe and produces ordered batches for sequential stream.

If you want to apply an intermediate transformation for every batch, you may use the following version:

```
public static <T, AA, A, B, R> Collector<T, ?, R> unorderedBatches(int batchSize,
        Collector<T, AA, B> batchCollector,
        Collector<B, A, R> downstream) {
    return unorderedBatches(batchSize, 
            Collectors.mapping(list -> list.stream().collect(batchCollector), downstream));
}
```

For example, this way you can sum the numbers in every batch on the fly:

```
List<Integer> list = IntStream.range(0,20)
        .boxed().parallel()
        .collect(unorderedBatches(3, Collectors.summingInt(Integer::intValue), 
            Collectors.toList()));
```

Comment: I would be very interested in seeing something like the parallel solution added to StreamEx (which has become a staple in my projects the way Guava and Lombok has). Less because I care about paralellism, but instead because it works on streams - StreamEx.ofSubLists requires you to already have a collapsed list, whereas my use cases are usually ongoing streams that I don't want to collapse into a Collection and have in memory all at once.

Comment: What about a parallel-friendly solution for an ordered steam?

I.E. convert a list of objects into a stream of Lists grouped by the ordered var? 

Ex: Send the list downstream once the ordered var changes?

Comment: "It's impossible to partition the arbitrary source stream to the fixed size batches" - absolutely not true. See my answer to related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27583623/is-there-an-elegant-way-to-process-a-stream-in-chunks/68913656#68913656

Answer (score 14):

I found an elegant solution using [`Iterables.partition`](https://guava.dev/releases/33.0.0-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#partition(java.lang.Iterable,int)) from [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava):

```java
Iterable<List<T>> parts = Iterables.partition(stream::iterator, size)
```

Comment: Iterables comes from Guava: https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.java Some developers may have good reasons not to use it. You should mention the third party libraries you use.

Comment: @gouessej I've updated this person's answer to indicate that it uses Guava

Comment: `Iterators.partition(stream.iterator(), size)` would be better than `Iterables.partition(stream::iterator, size)`.  As currently written, this solution is needlessly converting the `Iterator` to an `Iterable` so it can be passed to `Iterables.partition`.

Answer (score 10):

Provided you want to use the Stream sequentially, it is possible to partition a Stream (as well as perform related functions such as windowing - which I think is what you really want in this case). 
Two libraries that will support partitoning for standard Streams are [cyclops-react](https://github.com/aol/cyclops-react) (I am the author) and [jOOλ](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOL) which cyclops-react extends (to add functionality such as Windowing).

cyclops-streams has a collection of static functions [StreamUtils](http://static.javadoc.io/com.aol.simplereact/cyclops-react/1.0.0-FINAL/com/aol/cyclops/control/StreamUtils.html) for operating on Java Streams, and a series of functions such as splitAt, headAndTail, splitBy, partition for partitioning.

To window a Stream into a Stream of nested Streams of size 30 you can use the window method.

To the OPs point, in Streaming terms, splitting a Stream into multiple Streams of a given size is a Windowing operation (rather than a Partitioning operation).

```
  Stream<Streamable<Integer>> streamOfStreams = StreamUtils.window(stream,30);
```

There is a Stream extension class called [ReactiveSeq](http://static.javadoc.io/com.aol.simplereact/cyclops-react/1.0.0-FINAL/com/aol/cyclops/control/ReactiveSeq.html) that extends [jool.Seq](http://www.jooq.org/products/jOO%CE%BB/javadoc/0.9.7/org/jooq/lambda/Seq.html) and adds Windowing functionality, that may make the code a little cleaner.

```
  ReactiveSeq<Integer> seq;
  ReactiveSeq<ListX<Integer>> streamOfLists = seq.grouped(30);
```

As Tagir points out above though, this isn't suitable for parallel Streams. If you want to window or batch a Stream you wish to executed in a multithreaded fashion. LazyFutureStream in [cyclops-react](https://github.com/aol/cyclops-react)might be useful (Windowing is on the to-do list, but plain old batching is available now).

In this case data will be passed from the multiple threads executing the Stream to a Multi-Producer/Single-Consumer wait-free Queue and the sequential data from that queue can be windowed before being distributed to threads again.

```
  Stream<List<Data>> batched = new LazyReact().range(0,1000)
                                              .grouped(30)
                                              .map(this::process);
```

Answer (score 6):

It seem like, as Jon Skeet has shown in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32434592/partition-a-java-8-stream#comment52734181_32434592), it's not possible to make partitions lazy. For non-lazy partitions, I already have this code:

```
public static <T> Stream<Stream<T>> partition(Stream<T> source, int size) {
    final Iterator<T> it = source.iterator();
    final Iterator<Stream<T>> partIt = Iterators.transform(Iterators.partition(it, size), List::stream);
    final Iterable<Stream<T>> iterable = () -> partIt;

    return StreamSupport.stream(iterable.spliterator(), false);
}
```

Comment: I know it is an old topic, but it think is worth mentioning - it's not pure Java 8: `Iterators` class is from Guava.

Answer (score 5):

This is a pure Java solution that's evaluated lazily instead of using List.

```
public static <T> Stream<List<T>> partition(Stream<T> stream, int batchSize){
    List<List<T>> currentBatch = new ArrayList<List<T>>(); //just to make it mutable 
    currentBatch.add(new ArrayList<T>(batchSize));
    return Stream.concat(stream
      .sequential()                   
      .map(new Function<T, List<T>>(){
          public List<T> apply(T t){
              currentBatch.get(0).add(t);
              return currentBatch.get(0).size() == batchSize ? currentBatch.set(0,new ArrayList<>(batchSize)): null;
            }
      }), Stream.generate(()->currentBatch.get(0).isEmpty()?null:currentBatch.get(0))
                .limit(1)
    ).filter(Objects::nonNull);
}
```

The method returns `Stream<List<T>>` for flexibility. You can convert it to `Stream<Stream<T>>` easily by `partition(something, 10).map(List::stream)`.

Answer (score 2):

The most elegant and pure java 8 solution for this problem i found:

```
public static <T> List<List<T>> partition(final List<T> list, int batchSize) {
return IntStream.range(0, getNumberOfPartitions(list, batchSize))
                .mapToObj(i -> list.subList(i * batchSize, Math.min((i + 1) * batchSize, list.size())))
                .collect(toList());
}

//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23246983/get-the-next-higher-integer-value-in-java
private static <T> int getNumberOfPartitions(List<T> list, int batchSize) {
    return (list.size() + batchSize- 1) / batchSize;
}
```

Comment: Of course, this only works when the original stream is from a `List` (or if you're willing to create an in-memory copy of the stream as a `List` using `stream.toList()`).  It won't work for arbitrary streams of data that aren't backed by lists.

Answer (score 2):

The [JEP 461: Stream Gatherers](https://openjdk.org/jeps/461) Java 22 preview language feature adds built-in support for partitioning a stream in this manner:

```java
// [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6]]
Stream<List<Integer>> stream =
        Stream.of(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6).gather(Gatherers.windowFixed(3));
```

This uses the new [`Stream.gather`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#gather(java.util.stream.Gatherer)) method with the new built-in [`Gatherers.windowFixed`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Gatherers.html#windowFixed(int)) gatherer to convert the initial `Stream<T>` to a `Stream<List<T>>`.

---

Your question indicated that you wanted a stream of streams, not a stream of lists.  To do that, the standard existing [`Stream.map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map(java.util.function.Function)) method can then be applied to the previous result to convert the lists to streams:

```java
Stream<Stream<Integer>> stream = Stream.of(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
        .gather(Gatherers.windowFixed(3))
        .map(Collection::stream);
```

## Javadocs

[`Gatherer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Gatherer.html):

> An intermediate operation that transforms a stream of input elements into a stream of output elements, optionally applying a final action when the end of the upstream is reached. […]
>
> […]
>
> There are many examples of gathering operations, including but not limited to: grouping elements into batches (windowing functions); de-duplicating consecutively similar elements; incremental accumulation functions (prefix scan); incremental reordering functions, etc. The class [`Gatherers`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Gatherers.html) provides implementations of common gathering operations.

[`Stream.gather`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#gather(java.util.stream.Gatherer)):

> Returns a stream consisting of the results of applying the given gatherer to the elements of this stream.

[`Gatherers.windowFixed`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Gatherers.html#windowFixed(int))

> Returns a Gatherer that gathers elements into windows -- encounter-ordered groups of elements -- of a fixed size. If the stream is empty then no window will be produced. The last window may contain fewer elements than the supplied window size.
>
> Example:
>
> ```java
> // will contain: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8]]
> List<List<Integer>> windows =
>     Stream.of(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8).gather(Gatherers.windowFixed(3)).toList();
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is possible with some sort of hack inside:

create utility class for batch:

```
public static class ConcurrentBatch {
    private AtomicLong id = new AtomicLong();
    private int batchSize;

    public ConcurrentBatch(int batchSize) {
        this.batchSize = batchSize;
    }

    public long next() {
        return (id.getAndIncrement()) / batchSize;
    }

    public int getBatchSize() {
        return batchSize;
    }
}
```

and method:

```
public static <T> void applyConcurrentBatchToStream(Consumer<List<T>> batchFunc, Stream<T> stream, int batchSize){
    ConcurrentBatch batch = new ConcurrentBatch(batchSize);
    //hack java map: extends and override computeIfAbsent
    Supplier<ConcurrentMap<Long, List<T>>> mapFactory = () -> new ConcurrentHashMap<Long, List<T>>() {
        @Override
        public List<T> computeIfAbsent(Long key, Function<? super Long, ? extends List<T>> mappingFunction) {
            List<T> rs = super.computeIfAbsent(key, mappingFunction);
            //apply batchFunc to old lists, when new batch list is created
            if(rs.isEmpty()){
                for(Entry<Long, List<T>> e : entrySet()) {
                    List<T> batchList = e.getValue();
                    //todo: need to improve
                    synchronized (batchList) {
                        if (batchList.size() == batch.getBatchSize()){
                            batchFunc.accept(batchList);
                            remove(e.getKey());
                            batchList.clear();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return rs;
        }
    };
    stream.map(s -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(batch.next(), s))
            .collect(groupingByConcurrent(AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getKey, mapFactory, mapping(AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getValue, toList())))
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            //map contains only unprocessed lists (size<batchSize)
            .forEach(e -> batchFunc.accept(e.getValue()));
}
```

Comment: You are right about undocumented fact and it is reason why I called it 'hack'. Also you are right about non-atomic `computeIfAbsent`. I will edit code shortly. But why it is not lazy? It is not allocate all lists before processing one batch. Also it is common that concurrent batch processing is not ordered.

Comment: For parallel stream it doesn't work at all. `applyConcurrentBatchToStream(System.out::println, IntStream.range(0,100).boxed().parallel(), 3)` prints garbage (randomly collected groups, some elements repeating, even number of groups differ between runs). For sequential-only streams there are far simpler and more efficient solutions (like one presented by OP).

Comment: But you also show the source of bug: non-atomic `computeIfAbsent`.

Comment: As for ordering, it's not so common that concurrent batch processing is unordered. There's even special Stream API method `unordered()` which you may use to explicitly state that you don't care about order. In many cases you do care. And, I believe there's a simpler alternative for creating fixed size unordered batches...

Comment: I added fix for multithread issue, but I will think about it yet.

Comment: I posted my own unordered-parallel solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is a performant way

```
import java.util.AbstractList;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public final class Partition<T> extends AbstractList<List<T>> {

private final List<T> list;
private final int chunkSize;

public Partition(List<T> list, int chunkSize) {
    this.list = new ArrayList<>(list);
    this.chunkSize = chunkSize;
}

public static <T> Partition<T> ofSize(List<T> list, int chunkSize) {
    return new Partition<>(list, chunkSize);
}

@Override
public List<T> get(int index) {
    int start = index * chunkSize;
    int end = Math.min(start + chunkSize, list.size());

    if (start > end) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Index " + index + " is out of the list range <0," + (size() - 1) + ">");
    }

    return new ArrayList<>(list.subList(start, end));
}

@Override
public int size() {
    return (int) Math.ceil((double) list.size() / (double) chunkSize);
}
```

}

Usage

```
Partition<String> partition = Partition.ofSize(paCustomerCodes, chunkSize);

for (List<String> strings : partition) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is quick solution by [abacus-common](https://github.com/landawn/abacus-common)

```
IntStream.range(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE).split(size).forEach(s -> N.println(s.toArray()));
```

Disclaimer：I'm the developer of abacus-common.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pure Java 8 solution - both sequential and parallel:

```java
  public <T> Collection<List<T>> chunk(Collection<T> collection, int chunkSize) {
    final AtomicInteger index = new AtomicInteger();
    return collection.stream()
        .map(v -> new SimpleImmutableEntry<>(index.getAndIncrement() / chunkSize, v))
        // LinkedHashMap is used here just to preserve order
        .collect(groupingBy(Entry::getKey, LinkedHashMap::new, mapping(Entry::getValue, toList())))
        .values();
  }

  public <T> Collection<List<T>> chunkParallel(Collection<T> collection, int chunkSize) {
    final AtomicInteger index = new AtomicInteger();
    return collection.parallelStream()
        .map(v -> new SimpleImmutableEntry<>(index.getAndIncrement() / chunkSize, v))
        // So far it is parallel processing ordering cannot be preserved,
        // but we have to make it thread safe - using e.g. ConcurrentHashMap
        .collect(groupingBy(Entry::getKey, ConcurrentHashMap::new, mapping(Entry::getValue, toList())))
        .values();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava)-based solution will convert a `Stream<Integer>` into a partitioned `Stream<Stream<Integer>>`:

```java
Stream<Integer> stream = Stream.of(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);

// [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6]]
Stream<Stream<Integer>> partitioned =
        Streams.stream(Iterators.partition(stream.iterator(), 3))
                .map(Collection::stream);
```

## Walkthrough

1. Start with a `Stream<T>`

   ```java
   // [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
   Stream<Integer> stream = Stream.of(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
   ```
2. Convert to `Iterator<T>` using [`Stream.iterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/BaseStream.html#iterator()).

   ```java
   // [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
   Iterator<Integer> iterator = stream.iterator()
   ```
3. Partition to a `Iterator<List<T>>` using [`Iterators.partition`](https://guava.dev/releases/33.0.0-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterators.html#partition(java.util.Iterator,int)) in Guava.

   ```java
   // [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6]]
   Iterator<List<Integer>> iteratorOfLists = Iterators.partition(iterator, 3)
   ```
4. Convert to a `Stream<List<T>>` using [`Streams.stream`](https://guava.dev/releases/33.0.0-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Streams.html#stream(java.util.Iterator)) in Guava.

   ```java
   // [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6]]
   Stream<List<Integer>> streamOfLists = Streams.stream(iteratorOfLists)
   ```
5. Convert to a `Stream<Stream<T>>` using [`Stream.map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map(java.util.function.Function)).

   ```java
   // Stream<Stream<T>> [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6]]
   Stream<List<Integer>> streamOfStreams = streamOfLists.map(Collection::stream)
   ```