# Accumulating streams in java

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream, accumulate

Recently I've been trying to reimplement my data parser into streams in java, but I can't figure out how to do one specific thing:

Consider object A with timeStamp. 
Consider object B which is made of various A objects
Consider some metrics which tells us time range for object B.

What I have now is some method with state which goes though list with objects A and if it fits into last object B, it goes there, otherwise it creates new B instance and starts putting objects A there.

I would like to do this in streams way

Take whole list of objects A and make it as stream. Now I need to figure out function which will create "chunks" and accumulate them into objects B. How do I do that?
Thanks

EDIT:

A and B are complex, but I will try to post here some simplified version.

```
class A {
    private final long time;
    private A(long time) {
        this.time = time;
    }
    long getTime() {
        return time;
    }
}

class B {
     // not important, build from "full" temporaryB class
     // result of accumulation         
}

class TemporaryB {
    private final long startingTime;
    private int counter;

    public TemporaryB(A a) {
        this.startingTime = a.getTime();
    }

    boolean fits(A a) {
        return a.getTime() - startingTime < THRESHOLD;
    }

    void add(A a) {
        counter++;
    }
}

class Accumulator {
    private List<B> accumulatedB;
    private TemporaryBParameters temporaryBParameters
    public void addA(A a) {
         if(temporaryBParameters.fits(a)) {
             temporaryBParameters.add(a)
         } else {
             accumulateB.add(new B(temporaryBParameters)
             temporaryBParameters = new TemporaryBParameters(a)
         }
    } 
}
```

ok so this is very simplified way how do I do this now. I don't like it. it's ugly.

Comment: This is quite unclear. Could you give some code you tried? Maybe class `A` and `B` as a start?

Comment: This is still unclear. What is `someParameters`? What does "fits into" mean? What is `TemporaryBParameters`?

Comment: Instead of showing what you've tried so far, it would be useful to show more formal expected input / output. E.g. please replace "someParameters" by actual parameters, and show the result type and content of your "accumulation", given some specific input

Comment: So. You have a `List<A>`. For each element, you want to see if the elapsed time between this element and the previous is lower than a threshold. If it is, keep it; otherwise, disregard it. Collect that filtered list into a `List<B>`. Does that sound like what you want? If so, how to convert from one `A` to one `B`?

Comment: Don't you want to implement a `Collector`?

Comment: @Tunaki no, B consists of many A objects

Comment: @fge hmmm, maybe yes! I didn't know this. there is  A immutable list, mutable part of collection and B result of collection.

Comment: I'm trying again then. You have a `List<A>`. For each element, you want to see if the elapsed time between this element and the previous is lower than a threshold. If it is, keep it; otherwise, disregard it. Collect that filtered list into a `B`. Is this correct now? :)

Comment: I'm not sure this is well suited for a stream/collector. I guess a collector would be easy to implement if the stream is sequential, but for a parallel stream, since the B destination doesn't depend on the A alone, but also on the previous ones, this wouldn't fit. So, since the solution would only work with a sequential stream, why not use your current solution, which is clear and works well? You can still use `listOfAs.stream().forEachOrdered(accumulator::addA);`

Comment: You are going to have a hard time doing this with java8 streams because they aren't designed to produce this sort of flow. Basically you would need write a collector that starts with an empty List<List<A>> and then adds elements as needed.  You will then need to write an accumulator that knows not only what list to add a new element but also how to join two lists when an element bridges the gap.  Finally you will need a combiner that can take two List<List<A>> and find overlapping regions and combine them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general such problem is badly suitable for Stream API as you may need non-local knowledge which makes parallel processing harder. Imagine that you have `new A(1)`, `new A(2)`, `new A(3)` and so on up to `new A(1000)` with `Threshold` set to `10`. So you basically need to combine input into batches by 10 elements. Here we have the same problem as discussed [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32435407/4856258): when we split the task into subtasks the suffix part may not know exactly how many elements are in the prefix part, so it cannot even start combining data into batches until the whole prefix is processed. Your problem is essentially serial.

On the other hand, there's a solution provided by new [`headTail`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/one/util/streamex/StreamEx.html#headTail-java.util.function.BiFunction-java.util.function.Supplier-) method in my [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex/) library. This method parallelizes badly, but having it you can define almost any operation in just a few lines.

Here's how to solve your problem with `headTail`:

```
static StreamEx<TemporaryB> combine(StreamEx<A> input, TemporaryB tb) {
    return input.headTail((head, tail) ->
        tb == null ? combine(tail, new TemporaryB(head)) :
            tb.fits(head) ? combine(tail, tb.add(head)) :
                combine(tail, new TemporaryB(head)).prepend(tb), 
        () -> StreamEx.ofNullable(tb));
}
```

Here I modified your `TemporaryB` method this way:

```
TemporaryB add(A a) {
    counter++;
    return this;
}
```

Sample (assuming `Threshold` = 1000):

```
List<A> input = Arrays.asList(new A(1), new A(10), new A(1000), new A(1001), new A(
        1002), new A(1003), new A(2000), new A(2002), new A(2003), new A(2004));

Stream<B> streamOfB = combine(StreamEx.of(input), null).map(B::new);
streamOfB.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output (I wrote simple `B.toString()`):

```
B [counter=2, startingTime=1]
B [counter=3, startingTime=1001]
B [counter=2, startingTime=2002]
```

So here you actually have a lazy `Stream` of `B`.

---

**Explanation:**

`StreamEx.headTail` parameters are two lambdas. First is called at most once when input stream is non-empty. It receives the first stream element (head) and the stream containing all other elements (tail). The second is called at most once when input stream is empty and receives no parameters. Both should produce an output stream which would be used instead. So what we have here:

```
return input.headTail((head, tail) ->
```

`tb == null` is the starting case, create new `TemporaryB` from the `head` and call self with the `tail`:

```
    tb == null ? combine(tail, new TemporaryB(head)) :
```

`tb.fits(head)` ? Ok, just add the `head` into existing `tb` and call self with the `tail`:

```
        tb.fits(head) ? combine(tail, tb.add(head)) :
```

Otherwise again create new `TemporaryB(head)`, but also prepend the output stream with the current `tb` (actually emitting a new element into target stream):

```
            combine(tail, new TemporaryB(head)).prepend(tb),
```

Input stream is exhausted? Ok, return the last gathered `tb` if any:

```
    () -> StreamEx.ofNullable(tb));
```

Note that `headTail` implementation guarantees that such solution while looking recursive does not eat the stack and heap more than constant amount. You can check it on thousands of input elements if you doubt:

```
Stream<B> streamOfB = combine(LongStreamEx.range(100000).mapToObj(A::new), null).map(B::new);
streamOfB.forEach(System.out::println);
```