# Process elements N by N in a Java Stream

Tags: java, java-stream

I've got a single operation to retrieve a list of elements:

```
public EquipmentExchangeSet list(Set<Long> ids) {
    return restTemplate.getForEntity(equipmentServiceUrl + ids, 
        EquipmentExchangeSet.class).getBody();
}
```

Now I want to execute it subsequently making subsets of ids grouping them 1000 by 1000. That's the way I do it using Guava's [`Iterables#partition`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#partition(java.lang.Iterable,%20int)):

```
public EquipmentExchangeSet list(Set<Long> ids) {
    EquipmentExchangeSet result = new EquipmentExchangeSet();
    for (List<Long> idSubset : Iterables.partition(ids, 1000)) {
        result.addAll(restTemplate
                .getForEntity(equipmentServiceUrl + idSubset , EquipmentExchangeSet.class)
                .getBody());
    }
    return result;
}
```

However, it would be nice to process the id set with Java Streams. Is there a way to process the elements N by N using Java Streams?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32434592/partition-a-java-8-stream/32435407#32435407 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34405452/split-hashmap-to-partitions-in-java-8/34407196#34407196