# Uploading Large File Contents by Chunks

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api

I have data to upload on Facebook custom audience, files are usually 1 million + lines. Each line contain one mobile number. Facebook graph api support maximum 10000 mobile numbers to upload in single api call.

I am reading file by Java 8 Streams & then combine 10000 chunk and upload to facebook graph rest api.

It is happening serial way, and takes a lot of time. Is there any other best way to do it speedy?

Comment: Does this help? [Partition a Java 8 Stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32434592/partition-a-java-8-stream)