# Custom chunking of Lists Java 8

Tags: functional-programming, java-8, partitioning

I have 2 lists.

```
List<Integer> data = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);
List<Integer> partitionHelper = Arrays.asList(1, 3, 4, 5);
```

I want to distribute the `data` list into chunks using the `partitionHelper`.
For above example the output should be

```
List<List<Int>> partition = chunk(data, partitionHelper)
//partition = {{1}, {2,3,4}, {5,6,7,8}, {9,10}}
```

It can be safely assumed that `partitionHelper.sum()` >= `data.size()`. 
I need an O(n + m) algorithm preferably (where n = `partitionHelper.size()` and m = data.size())

Any pointers as to how `List<List<T>> chunk(List<T>, List<Integer>)` function implementation should look?

PS: I am looking for a functional style approach. **Not** the standard iterative one.

EDIT:

In Scala I would do something like this

```
def chunkList(data: List[Int], p: List[Int]): List[List[Int]] = {
  def chunk(data: List[Int], p: List[Int], acc: List[List[Int]]): List[List[Int]] =
    if (p.nonEmpty && data.nonEmpty) {
      chunk(data.drop(p.head), p.tail, acc :+ data.take(p.head))
    } else {
      acc
    }
  chunk(data, p, List())
}

> chunkList((1 to 10).toList, List(1,3,4,5))
> res2: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1), List(2, 3, 4), List(5, 6, 7, 8), List(9, 10))
```

Another Haskell implementation for both foldl and foldr can be found [here](http://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/beginners/2017-July/017665.html)

Comment: What do you mean _I need_? What happened when you tried to solve this yourself? Where did you get blocked?

Comment: I am trying to solve it using the map/flatMap constructs of java 8. Cannot wrap my head around how i should proceed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Partition a Java 8 Stream](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32434592/5221149)

Comment: @Andreas not really. that question talks about almost equal partitioning of streams. This is about partitioning a list into unequal chunks.

Comment: @ApoorvIngle Your question is a variant of the same problem, you just provide difference lengths to each partition. The important part is: *"It's impossible to partition the arbitrary source stream [...], because this will screw up the parallel processing."* --- Your question is an [**XY problem**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/351454). If you want to partition a `List<T>`, don't use Streams. Use a loop and `subList()` calls. It will also perform a lot better than any streaming implementation would.

Comment: Here is a running example of using `subList()`: [IDEONE](http://ideone.com/TYbQU2)

Comment: I have added a scala example to make things a bit clear.

Comment: @ApoorvIngle I don't know Scala, but to me that looks like a **recursive** function implementation. If that's what you want, why are you asking for a Java Stream implementation? You can do the exact same recursive function in Java. All you have to do is write it.

Comment: @Andreas i never asked for a stream implementation. I want a functional style implementation :)

Comment: @ApoorvIngle What is stopping you from writing a recursive function implementation, aka a functional implementation, in Java? *Hint:* You need to use `subList()` for *O(n)* performance.

Comment: @ApoorvIngle there is none, not in base Java.  Streams are really the only built-in Java approach to "functional style" on collections, and there's no real way to do this with streams.  If third-party libraries are game, you might as well just use Guava's `Lists.partition`.

Comment: `List<List<T>> result = new ArrayList<>(partitionHelper.size()); int i = 0; for (int size : partitionHelper) result.add(data.subList(i, Math.min(i += size, data.size())));`

Comment: @shmosel Thanks for inlining [my IDEONE code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44980009/custom-chunking-of-lists-java-8#comment76936025_44980009), minus the overflow handling.

Comment: @LouisWasserman `Lists.partition` is for (almost) equal chunks. I want the chunk size as a parameter to the function not necessarily equal sizes

Comment: @Andreas You're welcome :). The final `if` is unnecessary though.

Comment: @shmosel Not if there are more values than defined partitions. In case of overflow, all remaining values are added to extra overflow-partition. That's what the final `if` does.

Comment: @Andreas *It can be safely assumed that `partitionHelper.sum()` >= `data.size()`.*

Comment: @shmosel The `if` is good defensive programming. It does nothing at all if that assumption truly is guaranteed. Of course, defensive programming would also cover receiving zero or negative partition sizes, so I'm not on fully solid ground with my argument, but being the contrarian I am, I stand firm. ;-) --- *Update*: Actually, `subList()` indirectly guards against negative sizes, so maybe I'm on solid ground.

Comment: @Andreas If we're disregarding the stated premise, how can you determine that dumping the remainder into a custom partition is more correct than leaving it out or throwing an exception? Either way, defensive programming is an issue you should take up with OP; It doesn't invalidate my solution.

Comment: There's a reasonable way to do this using arrays and parallel prefix. Using streams is difficult since they lack a prefix/scan/cumulate operation, but it can be done if you stand on your head, e.g. using a stateful mapping function.

Comment: `public static List<List<Integer>> chunkList(List<Integer> data, List<Integer> p) {
    return chunk(data, p, 0);
  }

  public static List<List<Integer>> chunk(List<Integer> data, List<Integer> p, int k) {
    List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();
    if (p.get(k) >= data.size()) {
      result.add(data);
    } else {
      result.add(data.subList(0, p.get(k)));
      result.addAll(chunk(data.subList(p.get(k), data.size()), p, k + 1));
    }
    return result;
  }`

Comment: @AshwaniDausodia I understand there are iterative solutions possible. I am looking for a foldLeft version of it in Java if possible.

Comment: @ApoorvIngle Java has its own idioms and style of coding. If you try to use haskell/scala idioms in java, it will be asthetically bad and non performative. Also above code is not iterative. It is similar to your scala vesion except it uses index `k` to track current group rather than `head` and `tail` on `p`

Answer (score 0):

After translating your Scala code to Java, I ended up with the following code, which is useful only for a small `partitionHelper` list:

```
List<List<Integer>> chunk(List<Integer> data, List<Integer> p, List<List<Integer>> acc) {
    if (!p.isEmpty() && !data.isEmpty()) {
        int i = Math.min(p.get(0), data.size());
        acc.add(data.subList(0, i));
        return chunk(data.subList(i, data.size()), p.subList(1, p.size()), acc);
    }
    return acc;
}

List<List<Integer>> chunk(List<Integer> data, List<Integer> p) {
    return chunk(new ArrayList<>(data), p, new ArrayList<>());
}
```

Indeed, the `partitionHelper` list must be small, because the stack is being used for recursive calls of the `chunk` method, and there will be as many recursive calls as elements in the `partitionHelper` list.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i am looking for a foldLeft/foldRight kind of an implementation. Please see the Haskell link I have added to the question