# Is there a library to run large number of tasks serially as small batches of constant size tasks each?

Tags: java

I have to update `n` records. Due to some limitations, I cannot update more than `k` records in one go. So I want to do `n/k` iterations serially, and in each iteration update `k` records.

Is there a generic 3rd party library for splitting work load and doing it in batches (like how I want)? Almost all my googling pointed me to libraries which can parallelize work, but here I want to serialize it in batches.

I can own library, but I wanted to know if there was a 3rd party library that has some additionally capabilities like, ability to do some pre-work before and/or post-work after, the work, and doing something before and after each batch.

Comment: There are plenty of batch libraries.

Comment: Can you point me to one? As I noted, all batch libraries I was split work across various threads. I dont know if my requirement comes under 'Partitioning' or 'batch processing'.

Comment: I'd be surprised if you couldn't configure them for single threaded operation. It's a pretty basic requirement to allow both single and multithreaded batching.

Comment: I think these batching libraries attempt to split work across many threads, but not within one thread. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Related: [Partition a Java 8 Stream](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32434592/1542723)

Comment: You seem to assume that a library works in a single preset way and you can't configure it to behave differently.

Comment: You want to update `k` records in one go but just in a single thread? What do you then mean by in one go? Do you want to make one single request/db call which updates those `k` records?

Comment: @Simon yes, one single db request updating k records.

Comment: http://www.baeldung.com/java-list-split (lacks the pre/post processing hooks but shows several ways to partition a list)